# what "item size" really mean on Dynamo DB

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

Maybe I missed something here but it is not clear for me what "item size" really mean in this definition on DynamoDB documentation:

*One read capacity unit represents one strongly consistent read per second, or two eventually consistent reads per second, for **items up to 4 KB in size**. If you need to read an item that is larger than 4 KB, DynamoDB will need to consume additional read capacity units.*

Does it mean the entire size on storage? or the size of *read* data?

For example, there could be an item with size of 4 KB in the physical storage BUT I just read one attribute so the result size reading data is much less than 4 KB.

Any clarification would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you read or write an item even partially you consume the read or write for the whole item even if it is only partially read or written. In the case of reading the efficiency is only in what is transfered over the wire, not the consumed reads against the table.